# Is there a way to get back my lost photos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos, data-recovery

I accidentally restored an old backup on my iPhone and I lost some important photos.

I used EaseUs's data recovery app but it would only find the photos that I now have restored from the old backup, and not the ones that were lost.

Comment: You said "old backup".  You do not have a current backup?

Comment: The last time it was backed up was in 2019, and I didn't use it since then, but I also didn't get rid of it because of some photos. Now I remember that I have the pictures there so I said I would just take em to my PC, and when i opened iTunes I accidentally clicked on the restore backup pop-up window that showed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry.

The restore not only overwrote any older data but also destroyed the keys it was encrypted with.